# asp.net 4.0 intellisense not recognizing new strings added to global resources file in vs2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localization, resources

a question for all the people here. I am quite new to ASP.net and am having a problem with some code not working out. In the App_GlobalResources folder I have my localization files that translate strings in English and Spanish. They are called ls.resx and ls-es.resx and were setup sometime in the past.

I been asked to add some features to the site and this requires me to localize all the text so I added the new strings to these files and built the solutions. Then I tried to use it in the code.

If I use the localization files directly in the .aspx file it picks up the localization no problem at all. For example I use...

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelFName" runat="server" CssClass="label"
    Text="<%$ Resources:ls, FirstName %>"
    Width="140px"></asp:Label>
```

If I go to the code behind however and try to programatically set strings using the resources files I have problems however. If it is an old string that has previously been entered into ls.resx and ls-es.resx it works fine, for example...

```
lblWarning = Resources.ls.warningMissingData;
```

However if I try to use one of the new strings it is not picked up by the intellisense and I can not access it. It works fine the first method using <% %> so I know the string is there and the section built, I just can't access them in any code behind sections and I have no idea why it is not working.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your string to the resx's corresponding designer file as well.